# Converting Ensembl Compara gene tree DNA alignment to corresponding amino acid alignment

Tags: dna, bioinformatics, amino-acids, molecular-evolution, sequence-alignment

I have Ensembl compara gene tree alignments (Compara.gene_trees.57.fasta.gz downloaded from ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-57/emf/ensembl-compara/homologies/) in nucleotide format. According to documentation, it says that the file "contains the peptide alignment for every genetree in fasta format".

I was wondering what might be a handy tool to obtain the corresponding amino acid alignments from the file.

Thanks,

Ikram

Comment: The file is gzipped, so use a tool like 7zip or WinRAR to unzip it. After that, just open the fasta file in any text reader..?

Comment: Thanks Armatus for the comment. In fact I can view the file using zless in ubuntu. The problem is that the data is in nucleotide format (AGTC...) and I want it in amino-acid format (NGHIK... etc). I guess that, since the data is coding sequence, no frame shifts are needed and just a mapping from DNA-to-Protein might work (But I am not sure, and just want to confirm it before writing some code for it)

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, both within and without the world of bioinformatics, public FTP sites contain README files tat explain what each file offered by the FTP server contains. The file [README.protein_trees](ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-57/emf/ensembl-compara/homologies/README.protein_trees) states:

> Compara.gene_trees.{release}.emf.gz
>
> contains the peptide alignment for every genetree in emf alignment format
>
> Compara.gene_trees.{release}.fasta.gz
>
> contains the peptide alignment for every genetree in fasta format

This means that both [Compara.gene_trees.57.emf.gz](ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-57/emf/ensembl-compara/homologies/Compara.newick_trees.57.emf.gz) and [Compara.gene_trees.57.fasta.gz](ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-57/emf/ensembl-compara/homologies/Compara.gene_trees.57.fasta.gz) contain the protein alignments. I had a quick look at the files and it looks like `Compara.gene_trees.57.fasta.gz` actually contains nucleototide sequences but `Compara.gene_trees.57.emf.gz` does indeed contain a protein alignment:

```
$ zgrep -m 1 AAAAASAAAT Compara.gene_trees.57.emf.gz.crdownload 
SAAA-AHS-AGTAAAAA--AA--AAAAASAAAT-ASAATAI-SASSA-ASAAT-V----AAASVAA-HAFAS---ASAAASAAAAA-TIVAAAAX-SAASIYSAAAA-YAA--AASAS-ASAASAS-ASAASSSSSARS-AAS
```

So, to answer your question, the file you want is the `.emf.gz` one.